# RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory - CUDA Memory occurred at the validation stage

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the problem "CUDA error: out of memory" when my Deep Learning model runs validation. Although previously in the training stage, forward and backprop stages - which should have taken up a lot of memory with many saved gradients, the "CUDA error: out of memory" status did not appear.
My model has 21257650 Parameters. Training on GPU GTX 1070 8GB Memory.

##############The Error is below:###############

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 303, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 284, in main
    val_loss, val_psnr = validation(args, epoch, writer)
  File "main.py", line 144, in validation
    for i, (images, gt_image) in loop:
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1182, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 681, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1376, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1402, in _process_data      
    data.reraise()
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\_utils.py", line 461, in reraise
    raise exception
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in pin memory thread for device 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 34, in _pin_memory_lo
op
    data = pin_memory(data, device)
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 65, in pin_memory    
    return type(data)([pin_memory(sample, device) for sample in data])  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 65, in <listcomp>    
    return type(data)([pin_memory(sample, device) for sample in data])  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 65, in pin_memory    
    return type(data)([pin_memory(sample, device) for sample in data])  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 65, in <listcomp>    
    return type(data)([pin_memory(sample, device) for sample in data])  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Anh\anaconda3\envs\Kienv1\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\pin_memory.py", line 50, in pin_memory    
    return data.pin_memory(device)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Here is my validation code:

```
def validation(args, epoch, writer):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    losses, psnrs, ssims = utils.init_meters(args.loss, reset_loss=True)
    model.eval()
    criterion.eval()

    args.out_counter = 0  # Reset the output images index
    start = time.time()
    with torch.no_grad(): #no_grad() to my model tells PyTorch that I don't want to store any previous computations, thus freeing my GPU space.
        loop = tqdm(enumerate(val_loader), total=len(val_loader))
        for i, (images, gt_image) in loop:
            # Build input batch
            images = [img_.to(device) for img_ in images]
            gt = [gt_img.to(device) for gt_img in gt_image]
            print("gt len: " + str(len(gt)))

            # Forward
            out = model(images)  # out = [framet1, framet2]
            if device.type == "cuda":
                print(f"GPU Memory Usage: {torch.cuda.memory_allocated() / 1024 ** 3:.2f} GB")
            loss = 0
            loss_specific = []

            # Compute loss for each output
            for output, target in zip(out, gt):
                single_loss, single_loss_specific = criterion(output, target)
                loss += single_loss.item()  # use loss.item instead of loss which requires grads, solved the problem CUDA out Memory
                loss_specific.append(single_loss_specific)

            # Save loss values
            for k, v in losses.items():
                if k != 'total':
                    v.update(loss_specific[k].item())
            losses['total'].update(loss.item())

            # Calc metrics
            for output, target in zip(out, gt):
                utils.eval_metrics(output, target, psnrs, ssims)

            # Tensorboard
            if i % args.log_iter == 0:
                utils.log_tensorboard(writer, losses, psnrs.avg, ssims.avg.item(),
                                      optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'], epoch * len(train_loader) + i, 'val')

            # Save result images
            # if epoch % 15 == 0:
            #     epoch_path = os.path.join(args.save_path, args.result_images_folder, 'Epoch_' + str(epoch))
            #     utils.save_batch_images(args, out, gt, epoch_path)

            # update progress bar
            loop.set_description("(Val)")
            loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())

        # Calculatet execution validation time
        val_time_elapsed = time.time() - start

        # save val metrics to csv
        if epoch % 2 == 0:
            utils.save_metrics(args, os.path.join(args.save_path, args.graph_folder), epoch,
                               losses['total'].avg, psnrs.avg, ssims.avg.item(),
                               optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'], val_time_elapsed, 'val')

        print('Validating Results: \tValidation Loss: {:.6f}\tVal Time: {:.2f}'
              '\tPSNR: {:.4f}\tSSIM: {:.3f}'.format(losses['total'].avg, val_time_elapsed,
                                                    psnrs.avg, ssims.avg.item()))

        return losses['total'].avg, psnrs.avg
```

Comment: Ho big is your batch in the validation step compared to the training batch? How much memory is left while training on your GPU?

Comment: Thank you, i silly forgot about my validation batch size since i was using the different argument batch size for both val and train. I reduced the batch size in validation step and recieved no error now.

Comment: Glad that helped :) Could you please post your working code as edit so other people having a similar problem can see it?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems there is another process that is using your GPU. When running the validation, keep an eye on gpu memory (nvidia-smi)

There is a possibility due to large parameter size that after training gpu cache is full and it often gives OOM error. Use torch.empty_cache() after training and then perform validation